# Webpack 5: disableHostCheck

Tags: webpack

im serving webpack bundle for dev with kubernetes and get the following message:

```
Invalid Host header
```

Now i want to disable this with the option disableHostCheck, but it seems in the new version of webpack this option is removed.

Is there any other possibility?

Answer (score 17):

for me (**webpack-dev-server 4.6.0**), solution is :

```
devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        disableHostCheck: true,
}
```

to

```
devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        allowedHosts: "all",
},
```

---

**for the history,**

from [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/c5b9c7e8bc50f72f0fb27092249aeefaf0817840/CHANGELOG.md)

- the `disableHostCheck` and `allowedHosts` options were removed in favor of the `firewall` option

from migration [Guide](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/0002ebfbc8f36e92f91013372c9e2bca97022825/migration-v4.md) to v4

- The `disableHostCheck` option was removed in favor `allowedHosts: 'all'`: